# How to convert foreign key to normal column name in sql server

Tags: sql-server

I have a foreign key in one of my table called **Employee** and i want to change the foreign key column to normal column so I tried to drop foreign key

```
ALTER TABLE Group_Resources DROP CONSTRAINT <Foreign key Name>
```

but I could't do that I got following error

> is not a constraint. Could not drop constraint. See
>   previous errors.

then as a solution for above error I run bellow query(To create a constraint)

```
IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'fk_gr_res_resources')
BEGIN

    ALTER TABLE Group_Resources   ADD CONSTRAINT fk_gr_res_resources  
    FOREIGN KEY (resource_id)   REFERENCES Resources(id) /* make sure
    Resources.id is a PRIMARY KEY
```

then I run

```
ALTER TABLE Group_Resources
DROP CONSTRAINT fk_gr_res_resources
```

As I understand ,I dropped the `fk_gr_res_resources` not the foreign key
I can't understand what the solution is

Comment: "See previous errors" Did you see the previous errors? Also you have tagged both MySQL and SQL Server which aren't the same. Please remove the one you are not using.

Comment: I updated my question according to your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe you are confusing a column with a foreign key constraint. A constraint is an object that is linked to a table (for example a `CHECK` constraint) and some constraints need to be linked to a set of the table's columns, like a `PRIMARY KEY` or a `FOREIGN KEY`.

First, you create the table with it's columns, *then* you add a constraint to it like a foreign key that relates that table with another one. The `CREATE TABLE` syntax supports creating constraints on the same statement, so you can make them all at the same time.

You can't drop a column that is currently linked to a foreign key (be it on that table or from another one that's referencing that particular column). You have to drop the relevant foreign keys *first*, and then the column.

Use the following query to check all foreign keys currently created on your current session's connected database:

```
SELECT
    ConstraintName = C.CONSTRAINT_NAME,
    PrimaryKeyTable = QUOTENAME(PK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(PK.TABLE_NAME),
    PrimaryKeyColumn = CCU.COLUMN_NAME,
    ForeignKeyTable = QUOTENAME(FK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA) + '.' + QUOTENAME(FK.TABLE_NAME),
    ForeignKeyColumn = CU.COLUMN_NAME,
    UpdateRule = C.UPDATE_RULE,
    DeleteRule = C.DELETE_RULE
FROM
    INFORMATION_SCHEMA.REFERENTIAL_CONSTRAINTS C 
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS FK ON 
        C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = FK.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
        C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = FK.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND
        C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = FK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLE_CONSTRAINTS PK ON 
        C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_NAME = PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
        C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = PK.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND
        C.UNIQUE_CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = PK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.KEY_COLUMN_USAGE CU ON 
        C.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CU.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
        C.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = CU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND
        C.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = CU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
    INNER JOIN INFORMATION_SCHEMA.CONSTRAINT_COLUMN_USAGE CCU ON 
        PK.CONSTRAINT_NAME = CCU.CONSTRAINT_NAME AND
        PK.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG = CCU.CONSTRAINT_CATALOG AND
        PK.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA = CCU.CONSTRAINT_SCHEMA
WHERE
    FK.CONSTRAINT_TYPE = 'FOREIGN KEY'
ORDER BY
    PK.TABLE_NAME, 
    FK.TABLE_NAME
```

If you want to drop a column, just do `ALTER TABLE TableName DROP COLUMN ColumnName`

If you want to drop a constraint, just do `ALTER TABLE TableName DROP ConstraintName`

Answer (score 0):

You can delete a foreign key constraint in SQL Server 2017 by using SQL Server Management Studio or Transact-SQL. Deleting a foreign key constraint removes the requirement to enforce referential integrity.

```
USE <your_db>;  
GO
ALTER TABLE dbo.Group_Resources
DROP CONSTRAINT fk_gr_res_resources;
GO
```

Comment: I have already done this as I mentioned above question it runs successfully but foreign key is not removed that's why I am trying to convert it to normal column and also I am using sqlserver 2012

Comment: did you refresh the table? and it was not deleted?

Comment: Yes not deleted I also re-stated Sql Server but same result